# Adaptive Notifications re-enabling itself after some updates

Tags: notifications, android-10

I have a OnePlus 6T running Android 10 / OxygenOS 10.3.4. The problem I'm about to describe has, I believe, been present since the system upgrade to Android 10.

[image: Screenshot showing suggestions]

I started seeing these suggestions on various notifications - mainly from messaging apps; the above is a WhatsApp notification. I don't want them, and didn't have a clue how to turn them off because I didn't know what they were called.

Googling various related things ('suggestions', 'smart notifications', etc.) didn't get me any closer, but I eventually found some article on a feature that'd just debuted called 'Adaptive Notifications'. While it didn't mention the above behaviour explicitly, I figured this must've been it.

#### Switching them off (temporarily)

Sure enough, when I dug through my settings, found the option under *Apps & notifications > Special app access > Adaptive Notifications*, and switched it to 'None', these suggestions on notifications disappeared after a few minutes.

However, they periodically reappear after I apply a bunch of Play Store updates - and every time they do reappear, I find that 'Adaptive Notifications' has been re-enabled in my settings.

I'm unsure precisely what updates trigger this, but I'd hazard a guess at it being Play Services.

So, how do I stop this from happening?

Comment: @beeshyams I'm not sure I understand. Selecting 'Android Adaptive Notifications' makes the 'suggested actions' on notifications re-appear, which is exactly what I don't want.

Comment: Oh. OK. I thought on your device it appears different. Please ignore

Comment: I've just found out that these are called _smart actions_: https://www.xda-developers.com/smart-actions-set-reminders-notifications/ - still no idea how to get rid of them for good though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this setting keeps turning itself back on after certain updates, I've finally figured out how to switch off these 'smart actions' (apparently that's their actual name - see my above comment).

- As per the above, go to the Adaptive Notifications setting. **Switch it on.**
- Go to **Settings > Apps & Notifications > Notifications**.
- Scroll down and hit **Advanced**.
- Scroll down to **Suggested actions and replies**. Switch it off.

I'd seen this setting before, but it was greyed out. The missing step was re-enabling adaptive notifications.

[image: Screenshot of the above setting]